# Add item with icon to a menu in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, icons, menuitem

Is it possible to add a menu item with an icon (like the icons of undo/redo button) to a custom menu item?

The [documentation of the Class Menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addItem(String,String)) doesn't mention it, so I guess it's not possible, but maybe there's a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot add icons to custom menus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not use custom icons i suppose but you can use html character codes like this:

```
DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('☁ Cloud')
  .addItem(" Pen", 'showHtmlBlaBla')
  .addToUi();
```

You can look here for some [codes](https://html-css-js.com/html/character-codes/icons/)

Comment: Yes, all unicode emoji's and ascii symbols seem to work just fine.